# Calendar's startOfDay() gives incorrect time for some dates

Tags: ios, date

I'm getting a date one hour out when calling `startOfDay(for: )` with a parameter of `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)`

For example:

```
let twoThousandAndOne = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
let nineteenSeventy = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)

print("Two thousand and one: \(twoThousandAndOne)")
print("Nineteen seventy: \(nineteenSeventy)")

let calendar = Calendar.current

print("Start of two thousand and one: \(calendar.startOfDay(for: twoThousandAndOne))")
print("Start of nineteen seventy: \(calendar.startOfDay(for: nineteenSeventy))")
```

Output:

```
Two thousand and one: 2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
Nineteen seventy: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
Start of two thousand and one: 2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
Start of nineteen seventy: 1969-12-31 23:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: What is you locale ?

Comment: It's en-UK (BST) although I don't think that should matter, seeing as the results for twoThousandAndOne are correct but the nineteenSeventy values are out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your timezone is UTC+1

`Calendar` considers the local timezone but `print` displays dates in UTC.

To print the dates created with `Calendar` in UTC add the UTC timezone

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
```

Comment: Setting the timezone does fix this issue, but I'm confused as to why this issue is only shown the for nineteenSeventy date, but not the twoThousandAndOne one.

Comment: In UK 1970 BST was all-year and in 2001 not, see [here](https://greenwichmeantime.com/info/bst2/)

Comment: print displays dates in UTC. It took around a whole day of me to identify it. Ahhhh